How to test if a Sharepoint file exists?
First, sorry for my rusty english !
Before launching a process, I have to test if files are existing in a Sharepoint library.
My Microsoft environment (Visual Studio 2022) advise this:

WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.

I would like to have a function to use it like this:
If SharepointFileExist(strMyFile) then
else
endif

I try to use sample code I find in stackoveflow, but I can't succeed...
For exemple, this code doesn't work:
Private Function SharepointFileExist(ByVal strHost As String) As Boolean
 
    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strHost)
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        request.PreAuthenticate = True
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Call MsgBox("SUCCESS!!!")
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Call MsgBox("ERROR: " & ex.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
 
End Function

Can you give me the full content I need to achieve function SharepointFileExist()  ?
UPDATE: I tried this following code:
    Private Function SharepointFileExist_Test2(ByVal strHost As String) As Boolean
 Dim oRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = Nothing
 Dim oResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Nothing
 
 Try
     oRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strHost), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
     'Les 2 lignes suivantes permettent de s'authentifier automatiquement par exemple sur un site Sharepoint
     oRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = True
     oRequest.PreAuthenticate = True
     oResponse = CType(oRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
     Select Case oResponse.StatusCode
         Case Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
             oResponse.Close()
             Return True
         Case Else
             Return False
     End Select
 Catch generatedExceptionVariable0 As Exception
     Return False
 End Try
 End Function

Unfortunately, it returns:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Thank you in advance,

The function SharepointFileExist() I gave return the following error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Thank you for checking ! Can you give me news ?
